# InputField and TreeForm problem

Tags: inputfield, trees, expression-form

I want to use the expression enter by the user and form the Tree,
so I did TreeForm[test] as the picture show but it's not working.
But if I do it manually, it works.
[image]

Can anyone explain to me why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: try `TreeForm[ToExpression @ test]` ?

Comment: OMG, you're such a genius! Thank you so much! Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

TreeForm[ToExpression @ test]
Thanks to @kglr